# XSLT issue on getting specific children by tag of a particular element

Tags: xml, if-statement, xslt

I have a big problem on my XSLT file, when transforming I don't get the desired output. It's supposed to work, but I don't know where I made a mistake.

What am I trying to do?: In my xslt document, I'm trying to get each `/pizzaservice/pizzen/pizza/topping` element (this was easy), but then also get (when available) from each topping element the informations info (subelement) associated to each topping element (this is the matter now).

So before doing this, I wanted to test if
`/pizzaservice/basicToppings/topping/@name=/pizzaservice/pizzen/pizza/toppin`, I'm not sure I did it well. Maybe there are other possibilities to do that.

```
<!--Start of the XML code snippet-->
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <pizzaservice title="Pizza-Service">
        <basicToppings>
            <topping name="Timos Tomatensauce" id="Tomatensauce_Timos">
                <image url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Pizza_Margherita%2C_at_Restaurant_Gusto_%282013.07.13%29_2.jpg" copyRightShort="commons.wikimedia.org" copyRightLong="Arbeit von Lombroso aus Restaurant Gustro">
                </image>
                <info>aus ökologischem Anbau</info>
                <info>ohne Konservierungsmitteln</info>
                <info>laktosefrei</info>
            </topping>
            <topping name="Agro Tomatensauce" id="Tomatensauce_Agro">
                <image url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Pizza_Margherita%2C_at_Restaurant_Gusto_%282013.07.13%29_2.jpg" copyRightShort="commons.wikimedia.org" copyRightLong="Arbeit von Lombroso aus Restaurant Gustro">
                </image>
                <info>aus ökologischem Anbau</info>
                <info>mit Konservierungsmitteln</info>
                <info>laktosefrei</info>
            </topping>
            <topping name="Myrto Tomatensauce" id="Tomatensauce_Myrto">
                <image url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Pizza_Margherita%2C_at_Restaurant_Gusto_%282013.07.13%29_2.jpg" copyRightShort="commons.wikimedia.org" copyRightLong="Arbeit von Lombroso aus Restaurant Gustro">
                </image>
                <info>aus ökologischem Anbau</info>
                <info>mit Konservierungsmitteln</info>
                <info>laktosefrei</info>
            </topping>
    <!--...-->
    </basicToppings>

    <pizzen>
    <pizza name="Pizza Mozzarella" id="Pizza_Mozarella">
                <image url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Pizza_Margherita%2C_at_Restaurant_Gusto_%282013.07.13%29_2.jpg" copyRightShort="commons.wikimedia.org" copyRightLong="Arbeit von Lombroso aus Restaurant Gustro">
                </image>
                <topping>Myrto Tomatensauce</topping>
                <topping>geriebener Gouda Käse</topping>
                <topping>frisches Basilikum</topping>
                <size price="3.00" diameter="23cm">
                    Sehr klein
                </size>
                <size price="4.50" diameter="26cm">
                    klein
                </size>
                <size price="6.00" diameter="29cm">
                    mittelgroß
                </size>
                <size price="7.50" diameter="32cm">
                    groß
                </size>
                <size price="9.00" diameter="35cm">
                    Sehr groß
                </size>
            </pizza>
            <pizza name="Pizza Hawai" id="Pizza_Hawai">
                <image url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Pizza_Margherita%2C_at_Restaurant_Gusto_%282013.07.13%29_2.jpg" copyRightShort="commons.wikimedia.org" copyRightLong="Arbeit von Lombroso aus Restaurant Gustro">
                </image>
                <topping>
                Timos Tomatensauce
            </topping>
                <topping>
                frisch geraspeltem Edamer Käse
            </topping>
                <topping>
                Ananas
            </topping>
                <topping>
                Vorderschinken
            </topping>
                <size price="3.00" diameter="23cm">
                    Sehr klein
                </size>
                <size price="4.50" diameter="26cm">
                    klein
                </size>
                <size price="6.00" diameter="29cm">
                    mittelgroß
                </size>
                <size price="7.50" diameter="32cm">
                    groß
                </size>
                <size price="9.00" diameter="35cm">
                    Sehr groß
                </size>
            </pizza>
    </pizzen>
    </pizzaservice>
<!--End of the xml code snippet-->
```

XSLT:

```
<!--Start of the XSLT code snippet-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/pizzaservice/pizzen"/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="pizzen">
       <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="okay.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="pizza">
    <xsl:for-each select="topping"><xsl:value-of select="."/><!--allright works!--><br/>
    <xsl:for-each select="/pizzaservice/basicToppings/topping[@name='.']/info">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/><!--all info elements to the current topping here,this part don't work yet!--><br/>
    </xsl:for-each>

<!--End of the xslt code snippet-->

</body>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please refer this first :- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Be so kind and (a) post your XSLT (b) show us the expected output (c) clean up your XML (d) do not repeat yourself and (e) come up with a title that describes the nature of your problem.

Comment: Please choose a title for your question that says what your problem is, not a title that says it's a big problem and you need help.

Comment: now included Michael

Comment: @ManifestMan Your question is still not clear. You did not post the expected output, and you did not explain what the actual problem here is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. If I am guessing correctly, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:key name="topping" match="basicToppings/topping" use="@name" />

<xsl:template match="/pizzaservice">
    <html>
       <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="okay.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="pizzen/pizza"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pizza">
    <h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </h3>
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="topping"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="topping">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </li>
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('topping', normalize-space(.))/info">
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of a **key** to lookup the topping's info.

Applied to your input example, the result will look similar to this:

[image]

Comment: yes Michael right, that,s it ! Really great, i haven,t used the key function yet .